# Can't find tikz subfiles

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfiles

I've the following project structure:

```
./main.tex
./ch1/ch1.tex
./ch1/tikz1/tikz1.tex
```

The main.tex looks like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\subfile{./ch1/ch1.tex} 
\end{document}
```

The ch1.tex looks like:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfile{./tikz1/tikz1.tex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When I run the ch1.tex everything is ok, it finds the tikz1.tex, but when I run the main.tex it can't find the tikz1.tex.

Comment: Why don't you use `standalone` package/class?

Comment: I need them because the tikz code is very big and I don't want to confuse it with ch1.tex code.

Comment: I tried standalone but I got the same problem. Could you please show how to do it correctly?

Comment: The 'standalone' package didn't help because I still need to use 3 different .tex files, so the problem remains. The main.tex can't find the tikz.tex. Please help.

Comment: The main tex file doesn't include the package `subfiles`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Is that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @MarcoDaniel's observation that `\usepackage{subfiles}` was missing from the `main.tex` file, there is a problem with how you compile the documents because of relative paths.

When you compile  `main.tex`, `latex` looks in `<maindir>/ch1/` for `ch1.tex` and in `<maindir>/tikz1/` for `tikz1.tex`. When you compile `ch1.tex` (likely from its containing directory `<maindir>/ch1/`), `latex` looks in `<maindir>/ch1/tikz/` for `tikz1.tex`. Clearly, both of these cannot be correct, unless you maintain two copies of `tikz1.tex` which sort of defeats the purpose.

There are a number of ways to solve this:

1. Flatten the directory structure (might be OK depending on number of files)
2. Use absolute paths (not recommended for portability reasons)
3. Input `./ch1/ch1.tex` to `pdflatex` run from `<maindir>` when compiling `ch1.tex` on its own. Depending on the editor you use, there may be ways to set this up for files other than the main file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It used to compile but not on my new system.

I had a `main.tex` and a `Subfolder/firstChapter/subDoc.tex`. The file `subDoc.tex` has a tikz subfile included with the path `Subfolder/anotherFolder/tikz.tex`.

To compile the `main.tex` I had to use the relative path from `subDoc.tex` to `tikz.tex`: `../anotherFolder/tikz` not from `main.tex` to `tikz.tex`: `Subfolder/anotherFolder/tikz`.

Thinking about it, that totally makes sense. Perhaps this solution can help you.